# How to create a Silverlight Screencast?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

I would like to create a Screencast that can be played by a Silverlight player or embedded in a Silverlight application.   What program can I use to create the screen cast and how do I use the output with Silverlight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expression Encoder includes program to record yours screencast and edit it. 
http://www.devx.com/RIA/Article/38742/0/page/3